# How to check the given folder is a mount point

Tags: c, linux-kernel, mount, mount-point

I have to test the given folder path is a mount point or it is in local to my system with c code.

I read on net that `/etc/mtab` file have entry for mounted point. I can check that file but is their any system call or any function to check mount point.

My kernel version is `2.6.28.10`.

Comment: mount system call is there refer the man page: man 2 mount

Comment: mount system call will mount path, but i what to know that given path is mount point or local folder.

Comment: There is a command called mountpoint which will identify the path is mountpoint or not, but i dont know about the system call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These functions can be used for data structure access the mtab file:

```
FILE * setmntent(const char *file, const char *mode)

int endmntent (FILE *stream)

struct mntent * getmntent (FILE *stream)

struct mntent * getmntent_r (FILE *stream, struct mentent *result, char *buffer, int bufsize)

int addmntent (FILE *stream, const struct mntent *mnt)

char * hasmntopt (const struct mntent *mnt, const char *opt)
```

For more details about these functions refer the man page.

Answer (score 0):

On linux, getmntent() is suitable for parsing /etc/mtab.